# R Regression Modelling for Analysis on Firm performance based on Board Gender Diversity

Tags: r

I want to ask a question regarding R programming. I want to do an analysis where Firm performance is my dependent variable and Board gender diversity would be my  Independent Variable with Control variables:
No of Independent Director;
Size of Board;
Size of company.

What would be my code in this sceario?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could start by basic lineal regression:

Assuming:

- data.frame's name is data
- V1,V2...Vi control variables
- The code would be:

```
# With intercept: 

lm(performance~gender+V1+V2,data)
```

Interpretation: influece of gender over performace is a differential between gender =0 and gender = 1

```
# Without intercept:

lm(performance~gender+V1+V2-1,data)
```

Interpretation is the average influence of each gender over performace.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Also I have one confusion , if I have two groups one with female and other one without female on board, then which code should I use in this case.  if you have some reference document it would be really helpful!!

Comment: Glad to help. In that case you need the interaction as well. I rather use no intercept aproach but thats up to you. lm(performance~gender+V1+V2+gender*board,data) . Being board a dichotomic variable as well. For reference you could look up, Wooldridge 's Econometrics book.

Comment: If you have females and females on board as one single variable you need to treat that as a factor, otherwise if female and board are both dichotomic variables use the aproach i told u. Please send and example of your data structure to be sure.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.. so in that it means that I should:    lm(performance~gender+IndependentDirector*gender+Firmsize+gender*board,data) as my code as Independent director is also Dichotomic variable

Comment: Company TotalFemaleDirectors IndependentDirectors TotalDirectors  FirmSize  ROA ROE TobinQ
Audi AG 1 0 7  $48,444.74  12.27 18.64% 0.96
Renault 6 10 17  $46,675.13  0.89% 3.63% 0.83
ZF Friedrichshafen AG Germany 1 0 7  $38,696.13  1.76 12.3 0.06